# How to properly use the LockService in an WebApp deployed by google app scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am pretty new using google scripts and I am having trouble to understand the properly way to use the LockService on google app scripts, specifically on a webapp. I am currently developing a webapp that is going to be accesed by 25 different users, and they could be maybe accesing on the same period of time, and I want to avoid collisions since there is important information that is going through this script.

I have already read about the LockService and I do understand the concept, it is supposed to prevent from different users to access part or the whole code involving the lock at the same time, right? But I am not sure wether I should implement it on the .gs file or in the html, and how.
Here I leave the main part of my code:

INDEX

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content ="width">
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="customerForm">
      <div id="output"></div> 
      <div id="signature"></div><br>
      <img id="rendered" src="" style="display:none">
      <input type="button" value="Enviar Firma" onclick="renderSignature();saveImage()"/>  </body>
    </form>
</html>
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('JavaScript').getContent(); ?>
```

SCRIPT TO MANAGE GS FILE RETURNS

```
<script>
//..some code
  function saveImage(e){ //This sends the image src to saveImages function
    //Assign values to bytes and sign variables
    };
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).compare_tickets(bytes, sign);
    google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure).compare_tickets(bytes, sign);
  } 
  function onSuccess(bytes){
     google.script.run.saveImage(bytes)
  }
  function onFailure(error) {        
    //Throw alert with the error
  }
</script>
```

GS File

```
function doGet(e){
  return HtmlService
    .createTemplateFromFile("index")
    .evaluate()
    .setTitle("Firme aquí por favor")
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function compare_tickets(bytes, sign){ //first function runned by the index
    //some code that reads Some spreadsheets 
}

function saveImage(bytes){    //second function runned by the index
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  if(lock.tryLock(10000)){
    //Do operations/readings/writings on different spreadsheets in case you get the lock
    lock.releaseLock();
  }                                                                               
  else{
    //Tell the user that the system is busy and should retry to send the info
  }
}
```

So the code above shows that I am trying to implement the LockService on the GS file, I have already tried to access from 3 different browsers at the same time but it looks like the 3 of them are actually running the code, and some information is lost, I guess that the lock is not working as I thought it would.

Could you please help me to figure out how to implement the locks? 
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your script - the lock should work perfectly fine - try adding a check that ensures that all changes to spreadsheets are finished before returning from `saveImage()` - to check if this is the case [I am referring to server-side code], add a `Utilities.sleep(t)`  call before the `lock.releaseLock()` with `t` set to >= number of milliseconds it takes your spreadsheet logic to complete (after some experimenting with this value, overlapping should disappear)

Comment: I believe you should combine these `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).compare_tickets(bytes, sign);
    google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure).compare_tickets(bytes, sign);` into this `google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure).withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).compare_tickets(bytes, sign);`

Comment: Thank you for the tip Oleg! I will try to find that time, it is supposed to be around 10secs acording to most of the executions times that I ran. 

And Cooper, I did not know that I could call these methods like that, I'll make the correction thanks!

Comment: Update: as you stated Oleg, I had to experiment with different times and I could finally make it work! Thank you so much for your answer.